# Орфононимы: я ли их открыл-таки?

Tags: орфография

Вот вы спрашивали, что же такое *орфононим*, а вот и получайте, сэры́! На Новый год от Лео объяснение-подарочек личное!

Мой вопрос есть всё-таки: а я, Лео, не изобрёл велосипед? Может быть, уже было — тогда какое? — название такой вещи? (Пожалуйста, — в честь Нового года, в конце концов, — не делайте так, чтоб этот вопрос закрыли.)

https://youtu.be/1uKjQWxDaCI?si=8JWQGx8RekOmDun1

Comment: Что-то в Правилах сайта есть эдакое о ссылках, типа низя.

Comment: Я потом и говорю, чтоб вы подарок сделали.

Comment: Зачем создавать непонятные вопросы?

Comment: Сделайте подарок себе и другим: читайте, читайте и читайте.